# Why is my first-of-type CSS selector applying to everything?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to target the first h3 of the page, but hitting all h3s instead. I've tried below, and with `>`, but that only works when it's directly inside the body and not nested.

```
body h3:first-of-type{ /*code*/ }
```

Any ideas?

I don't want to resort to adding IDs everywhere.

https://jsfiddle.net/M2X9z/

Comment: Can you add some sample html?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7u9uC/

Comment: Providing some html will help, but as others have mentioned using `first-of-type` is probably not the best way to go. You say you don't want to add IDs everywhere, but surely you only need to add 1 ID to the `<h3>` element you want to style? People try to complicate things too much.

Comment: I was trying to keep cleaner html, and also couldn't be bothered mass adding multi classes over the pages! But looks like thats now on the agender. Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`First-of-type` will target the first element of that type within its parent, not within the ancestor you've specified.  So if your HTML was like

```
<body>
   <div>
      <h3>first</h3>
   </div>
   <div>
      <h3>second</h3>
   </div>
</body>
```

then both `h3` elements will be targeted because each is the first `h3` within its parent.

Given that you only want to target one element, it does seem like adding an id is the sensible approach.

(It would also be possible to do this with jQuery (which has a `:first` selector), though that of course would depend on javascript being enabled, and is probably overkill if you don't need it for other reasons.)

Comment: Kiee, because of this, and you only want the first `h3` of a page, why not give it a class?  This way it can target this specific `h3` across multiple pages if needed.

Comment: Yes I was just trying to evade the inevitable and hope someone could off a work around!

Comment: If you're willing to utilize PHP or some server-side language, you can modularize your HTML files so that you only need to edit one file to see a change across multiple pages.  An example would be a file that contains the HTML for the navigation or header, which is included on every page.  You would only need to edit this header file once, since the file is included/inserted into each page.

Comment: Down-voted for mentioning jQuery.

Comment: Wow how did I learn this just today, great answer

Answer (score 3):

#### Try This

```
body > div:first-child h3:first-of-type {
    color : red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The :first-of-type pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo

So thats not going to work, you should just give it an id and use that to select it.

Answer (score 1):

`first-of-type` is working well **only from its parent**:

```
h3:first-of-type
{
   color:green;
}
```

Html

```
<h3>first</h3>
<h3>second</h3>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zQmR6/ does work!

---

If you have different `div`, every first `h3` inside the `div` is considered the first one.

```
<div>
<h3>first</h3>
</div>
<div>
<h3>second</h3>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RMpGq/ does not work!

Comment: The problem with that is the selector will target the first `h3` for every parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try:
`body h3:first-child`
 The first-child pseudo element describes the element itself, not the children of the element.
 The space specifies that you are looking for descendants of the body. Since you are not looking for direct descendants , you should not use `>`.

Comment: As explained, I tried that but it only works when the h3 is directly within the body and not nested

Comment: @kiee in that case you need a space, see updated answer

Answer (score -1):

Njoy

```
h3:first-of-type {
     color: red;
 }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/D277X/

```
p:nth-of-type(1) {color:yellow; }
```

Comment: nth of type (1) is the same as first of type